# node.js when user clicks refresh on browser go to specific page

Tags: node.js, page-refresh

I have a working little web app made with node.js

When the user clicks "refresh" on the browser from whatever page, I need to load the "main" page.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: In Javascript [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) exists. This is called, when refreshing or leaving your page. You could use that to call a redirect function. But then it would also redirect, when you close the browser or change the page. So, might not exactly be, what you are looking for.

Comment: @Geshode I tried that and the page doesn't redirect, probably because of the refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="tobereload">Load the main page</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("tobereload").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location = "/"
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi, how will this div intersect the click to the refresh button on the browser please?

Comment: There is no way to catch event from "refresh button on the browser". You gotta write browser extension, i guess.